# Creating an arbitrary property in my Model

Tags: cakephp, model

Here's my Model:

```
class Persona extends AppModel {

    // This is just some arbitrary property I need to populate in the controller.
    public $TipoPersona = ''; 
}
```

And here is the Action function in my Controller:

```
public function details($id = null) {

    // Just a typical load by id.
    $this->Persona->id = $id;
    $this->set('persona', $this->Persona->read()); 

    // Can I do something like?
    $this->Persona->TipoPersona = "Mafa Woogly";
}
```

How can I set the `$TipoPersona` property in the "Model" here? My intent is to then use that property in the View like:

```
<tr>
    <th>Tipo de Persona:</th>
    <td><?php echo h($persona->TipoPersona); ?></td> // Or similar?
</tr>
```

Any suggestions?

This works, but feels wonky and not strongly typed.

```
public function details($id = null) {
    $this->Persona->id = $id;
    $this->set('persona', $this->Persona->read());
    $this->set('tipoPersona', "Mafa woogly");
}

<tr>
    <th>Tipo de Persona:</th>
    <td><?php echo h($tipoPersona); ?></td>
</tr>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to add it directly with set:

```
$this->set('tipoPersona', $this->Persona->TipoPersona);
```

it's property like everyone else in the model. The same way you are setting  $this->Persona->id few lines above :)

Answer (score 1):

The method `read()` return an array, you can't get the property `TipoPersona` of this object.

I recommend you add a field in this table to specify type of person and than use the result of `read()`, like:

```
<?php echo $persona['Persona']['tipo_persona']; ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could add it to the result array using Model::afterFind() callback.

Are you sure this shouldn't be a regular field in the Model?